onEdit() functionality when performing undo operation in sheets
I am developing a basic functionality in my spreadsheet where if data is entered in two cells, a category name and amount, they will populate another part of the spreadsheet and then be cleared from where they were originally entered. This is making use of the event object in appscript that enables one to perform an action if a cell is edited. The problem I am having is there are unfortunate side effects once I have logged the event and performed the action.
If I hit ctrl+z to undo what I did and the two cells where I originally entered the data are populated, the event is re-triggered, forcing my spreadsheet to enter a loop where I can't undo the data that was logged. Is there a way around this effect? I tried using the oldValue field of the event object but it's not working the way I want. My initial approach was to try and only perform the action when the cells were previously undefined. It turns out that when I undo, the cells were also previously undefined and the loop begins. Is there a way around this?

function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  //Events
  let range = e.range;
  let oldVal = e.oldValue;

  //Expense Category added or deleted
  addCategory(sheet, range, oldVal);
}


function addCategory(sheet, range, oldVal) {
  let row = range.getRow();
  let col = range.getColumn();
  let addRange            = "I7:I9";
  let categoryRange       = "F12:F";
  var category2Add        = "I7";
  let amount2Add          = "I8";
  let startRow            = 12;
  let categoryColumn      = 6;
  
  //There is add category request but no amount entered
  if (row == 7 && col == 9 && sheet.getRange(amount2Add).isBlank()) {
    //SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("I'm here");
    return;
  }
  //There is add category request but no category entered
  if (row == 8 && col == 9 && sheet.getRange(category2Add).isBlank()) {
    //SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("yaya");
    return; 
  }
  if (row == 7 && col == 9 && !sheet.getRange(amount2Add).isBlank() && typeof oldVal === 'undefined') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("test 1 is: " + oldVal);
    doWork(sheet, startRow, categoryColumn, sheet.getRange(amount2Add).getValue(), sheet.getRange(category2Add).getValue(), categoryRange, addRange);
    return;
  }
  if (row == 8 && col == 9 && !sheet.getRange(category2Add).isBlank() && typeof oldVal === 'undefined') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("test 2 is:  " + oldVal);
    doWork(sheet, startRow, categoryColumn, sheet.getRange(amount2Add).getValue(), sheet.getRange(category2Add).getValue(), categoryRange, addRange);
    return;
  }
  return;
}

function doWork(sheet, startRow, categoryColumn, amount, category, categoryRange, transferRange) {
  //Entry is a negative number
  if (amount < 0) {
    Browser.msgBox("Initial amount must be greater than zero!");
    sheet.getRange(transferRange).clearContent();
    return;
  }
  //Entry is not a number
  if (isNaN(amount)) {
    Browser.msgBox("Initial amount must be a number!");
    sheet.getRange(transferRange).clearContent();
    return;
  }
  let expenseCategoryList = sheet.getRange(categoryRange).getValues().filter(r => r!= "").flat();
  let row2Add             = expenseCategoryList.length;
  let categoryCell        = sheet.getRange(startRow + row2Add, categoryColumn);
  let categoryAmountCell  = sheet.getRange(startRow + row2Add, categoryColumn + 2);
  categoryCell.setValue(category);
  categoryAmountCell.setValue(amount);
  sheet.getRange(transferRange).clearContent();
  return;
}



Does this answer your question? Can I exclude operations from the undo stack in Google Apps Script?

You might try using an installable trigger instead of a simple trigger to see if that behaves better.

@Blindspots It's a little hard for me to understand what the nature of the problem is in the link you provided. More so given that the problem was not illustrated with any code examples. Regarding installable triggers, can you highlight why an installable trigger would work for the example problem I highlighted?

There are differences in event object e, which can be used to differentiate. Try logging the object when you do the actual action and when you do the action you don't want triggered and see if they are keys that can be used to differentiate. Checkout my answer.

@J_code The answerer suggested that making the changes outside the account performing the edits could avoid adding the changes to the undo queue (may have been in a comment).

It's crucial to refrain from using undo and redo in Google Apps Script. Doing so can help you steer clear of potential issues and maintain the integrity of your data.
Google Apps Script doesn't include methods for determining when a user has edited a spreadsheet by typing, pasting, or executing an "undo" or "redo" command.
If your spreadsheet is shared or you cannot avoid undo or redo, consider adding a means to "turn off" the onEdit trigger. I.E. You might add a checkbox and use its state to control the onEdit flow, like in the checkbox is checked exit before doing any change.
A second approach might be to keep a log of the changes made by each user. To keep it short, you can use an on-open installable trigger to clear the log entries corresponding to the user who has opened the spreadsheet and, once a day, delete all log entries.
A third approach might be to use the Google Drive API to get the spreadsheet revisions.
Related

Writing an 'Undo' Function for Google Spreadsheets Using GAS
Google Sheets undo/redo function
This question has a Tainake's answer, including a demo script to implement undo / redo using Apps Script.
I am unable to undo more than one step back when using a particular Apps Script
How to obtain contents of previous versions of google sheets using Python and Google APIs


Thanks for your answer. Your second paragraph gets to the crux of the issue. Essentially I wanted apps script's onEdit functionality to have a way of distinguishing between editing a cell and undoing a cell, where undoing a cell does not execute the trigger. I will investigate your second approach in more detail but for now, I will incorporate a variant of your first approach and tie the functionality to a push button to mitigate the effect described in my original post, so that the operation will execute only when the button is pushed.
